# Unable to get springboot actuator metrics in prometheus-adapter

Tags: prometheus, kubectl, spring-boot-actuator, prometheus-operator

Have configured prometheus-operator to capture springboot pod metrics (via actuator).

Able to query on prometheus graph UI for the metric `http_server_requests_seconds_count`

```
kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 | jq . | grep http_s
```

But the same `http_server_requests_seconds_count` metric is not visible when querying the `custom-metrics api`

Output of cm describe for the adapter

```
Namespace:    custom-metrics
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
config.yaml:
----
rules:
- seriesQuery: 'http_server_requests_seconds_count{job="kubernetes-pods", app="eperfall-priceservices"}'
  seriesFilters: []
  resources:
    overrides:
      kubernetes_pod_name:
        resource: pod
      kubernetes_namespace:
        resource: namespace
  name:
    matches: http_server_requests_seconds_count
    as: requests_per_second
  metricsQuery: rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{job="kubernetes-pods", app="eperfall-priceservices", uri="/priceservices/actuator/prometheus", <<.LabelMatchers>>}[5m])

Events:  <none>
```

Describe of the prometheus-adapter pod

```
Name:               custom-metrics-apiserver-7496cc665f-v9mrd
Namespace:          custom-metrics
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               ip-10-157-198-239.ec2.internal/10.157.198.239
Start Time:         Mon, 30 Sep 2019 03:46:00 +0000
Labels:             app=custom-metrics-apiserver
                    pod-template-hash=7496cc665f
Annotations:        kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.157.218.96
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/custom-metrics-apiserver-7496cc665f
Containers:
  custom-metrics-apiserver:
    Container ID:  docker://6f4f1224403a290c403712341f263765409404d3b86900622a02b5cdb08bd7b1
    Image:         directxman12/k8s-prometheus-adapter-amd64
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://directxman12/k8s-prometheus-adapter-amd64@sha256:ad5b5da5c5630c3b57cc5986d04067548c6ecf5407fd5e789cf34715b9dd31d3
    Port:          6443/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      /adapter
      --secure-port=6443
      --tls-cert-file=/var/run/serving-cert/serving.crt
      --tls-private-key-file=/var/run/serving-cert/serving.key
      --logtostderr=true
      --prometheus-url=http://prom-prometheus-operator-prometheus.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:9090/
      --metrics-relist-interval=1m
      --v=10
      --config=/etc/adapter/config.yaml
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 30 Sep 2019 03:47:35 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/adapter/ from config (ro)
      /tmp from tmp-vol (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from custom-metrics-apiserver-token-t7bmh (ro)
      /var/run/serving-cert from volume-serving-cert (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  volume-serving-cert:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  cm-adapter-serving-certs
    Optional:    false
  config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      adapter-config
    Optional:  false
  tmp-vol:
    Type:    EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
  custom-metrics-apiserver-token-t7bmh:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  custom-metrics-apiserver-token-t7bmh
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

Comment: Are you doing this in correct namespace? Can you how `describe` of prometheus adapter?

Comment: The pods were launched in a specific namespace and also in default namespace. Both ways, unable get the custom metrics

Comment: Added the describe output of the confimap used for prometheus adapter.

Comment: Sorry I've meant describe for Prometheus adapter pod.

Comment: Added the describe of the Prometheus adapter pod